# Laravel 4 Pagination bug with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using Laravel Pagination, I believe that the css classes generated are relevant to bootstrap 2 and not bootstrap 3.

`{{ $products->links() }}` generates

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However I would like it to generate:

```
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
    </ul>
```

Without changing the framework code `laravel/framework/src/illuminate/pagination/views/slider.php`, is there a better / proper way of overriding the CSS / code generated by `{{ $products->links() }}`?

Comment: The correct answer which you have marked is actually correct but the second solution is more accurate. Can you change that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I saw something in one of the latest update, I haven't tried but it looks like all you have do do is change:

'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',

In the view config to:

'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',

This then uses:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider-3.php

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can :)
edit /app/config/view.php to specify the pagination value:

```
<?php
return array(
    'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
    'pagination' => 'elements/pagination',
);
```

after that, create a `view/elements/pagination.php`, and put + modify the content of the following file: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider.php

Comment: NP. There is a pull request for this. Watch it at: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/421

Answer (score 0):

There is an update as said by "crynobone" on laravel forum.

4.0.*@dev (to be released as 4.0.8) now include a new view for bootstrap 3. Follow this step to have it as default

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13256