# Bootstrap 3: How to keep pagination on one line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the pagination of Bootstrap 3 working fine.
Except one thing:
The pagination does not remain on one line but go on a new line.
For example on the phone view i have three lines of numbers of the pagination.
The question is: how can i force to keep the pagination on one line?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the `<ul>` to a big value seems to work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="pagination" style="width:100000px;">
```

Maybe calculate the real width with javascript / jquery.

Also consider to not display all values but something like : < 1 2 3 ... 1007 >

Comment: The first solution is not working properly, because it keep the site quite long on the right.
I am interested in the last solution, how can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: How do you construct your pagination? Do you use a CMS? in What language, etc.

Comment: I am using Laravel 4. That i can integrate well with Bootstrap.
This is the original line of code:
    {{ $newsletterUsers->links() }}
That create a <ul class="pagination">

Comment: Sorry, i don't know anything about Laravel 4. It seems you will have to look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/BootstrapPresenter.php. See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766753/laravel-4-pagination-bug-with-twitter-bootstrap-3. Maybe set 13 to a lower value `if ($this->lastPage < 13)` (line 49 in BootstrapPresenter.php) will do the trick.

Comment: Ok, that set the minimum amount of elements to create a pagination.
I try to change some values but not find the right solution.
With plain html, how you can modify the pagination in order to <1 2 3 ... 25>?

Comment: now your results (pagination) are will be set by `$content = $this->getPageRange(1, $this->lastPage);` while `$content = $this->getPageSlider();` should give the desired result. What's your output when setting `if ($this->lastPage < 13)` to `if ($this->lastPage > 0)`? For plain html see: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

Comment: It remains the same, the pagination is displayed normally.
I try again to change some settings but it mess up the pagination.

Comment: consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766753/laravel-4-pagination-bug-with-twitter-bootstrap-3 in the case of your pagination messed up. Maybe try to update your question with new results and changes you have made.

Comment: Maybe on tablet and phone i can show a different pagination no?